# ¿Cómo puedo comparar dos datasets (Arraylist) en java?

Tags: java

Tengo esta duda, tengo dos `arraylist`:

```
Dataset1=[["Value1",0,34,100,20],["Value2",3,42,150,30],["Value3",1,2,45,3]]

Dataset2=[["Value1",2,34,120,20],["Value2",4,2,10,130],["Value3",1,22,5,35]]
```

Por ejemplo, comparar:

```
Dataset1["Value1",0,34,100,20] vs Dataset2["Value1",2,34,120,20]

Dataset1["Value2",3,42,150,30] vs Dataset2["Value2",4,2,10,130]

Dataset1["Value3",1,2,45,3] vs Dataset2["Value3",1,22,5,35]
```

Ver si sus valores son diferentes, si son diferentes, deben regresar la diferencia en porcentaje. Por ejemplo:

> Dataset1["Value3",1,2,45,3] vs Dataset2["Value3",1,22,5,35] 1 vs 1 =
> Pass 2 vs 22 = Si hay diferencia por lo tanto sacar el porcentaje de
> la diferencia entre esos dos valores->

```
result=((Dataset1Val-Dataset2Val)/Dataset2Val)*100  = ((2-22)/22)*100 = -90%
```

Para obtener otro `arraylist` como resultado:

```
DataSetResult=[["Value1",result%,result%,1result%,result%], 
               ["Value2",result%,result%,1result%,result%], 
               ["Value3",result%,result%,1result%,result%]]
```

(Si esta bien esa formula para obtener el porcentaje de la diferencia entre esos dos valores)?

Yo me imagino un método así:

```
compareDataSet(ArrayList DataSet1, ArrayList DataSet2){


return DataSetResult;

}
```

Todo esto en java

Answer (score 0):

yo no tengo DataSet para trabajar lo que pides, pero la lógica es la misma:

```
    Integer[] a= {0,34,100,20}; //tu Array A

    Integer[] b= {2,34,120,20}; //tu Array B

    final List<Integer> listA =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
    final List<Integer> listB =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Collections.addAll(listA, a);
    Collections.addAll(listB, b);

    Log.d("LISTA", "metodo: " + "\n" + listA + "\n" + listB);
    if(listA.equals(listB)){
        Log.d("LISTA", "Iguales ");
    }else{
        Log.d("LISTA", "Distintos ");
        double sumA = 0;
        double sumB = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++) {
            sumA += listA.get(i);
            Log.d("LISTA", "valores lista A: " + sumA);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++) {
            sumB += listB.get(i);
            Log.d("LISTA", "valores lista A: " + sumB);
        }

        double porcentaje = ((sumA - sumB) / sumB) * 100;
        Log.d("LISTA", "porcentaje: " + porcentaje);
```

Eso me imprime el porcentaje que pides:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso, deberás remover el índice 0 de tus DataSet puesto que es un String. Eso puedes hacerlo así:

```
    Integer[] a = {0, 34, 100, 20};
    final List<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Collections.addAll(listA, a);
    Log.d("TODOS", "Todos: " + listA);
    listA.remove(0); //el número indica la posición
    Log.d("TODOS", "Sin un elemento: " + listA);
```

Lo que nos devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]